# Error popup appears when trying to open script in jmeter recorder by Blazemeter chrome extension

Tags: selenium, jmeter, blazemeter

I recorded a script using blazemeter and it was showing me to save in 2 formats: Selenium only, Jmeter and selenium combined.

[image]

I downloaded both formats and tried opening in JMeter 4.0 but that shows an error popup with no details.

[image]

Please let me know how to go ahead with jmx extension.

Comment: If someone still looking for it, you need to login to blazemeter via extension to be able to download jmx file. above save dialog comes without login and dialog in answer below comes after logging in.
you need to create account first obviously!

Answer (score 2):

You can open only `JMX` files in JMeter, make sure to choose `JMeter only (JMX)` option when saving your recorded script:

[image]

This type of recording can be normally opened with JMeter.

With regards to `Selenium only (YAML)` and `JMeter & Selenium combined (YAML)` - you can open them using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool.

If you need to convert Taurus YAML file into .jxm you can do the following:

1. [Install Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/)
2. Invoke the following command:

   ```
   bzt /path/to/recorded/test.yml -gui
   ```

Taurus will open the recorded script in JMeter GUI where you will be able to debug it, edit or save as .jmx script.

More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: Pretty helpful answer.